# Difference between these objects?

Tags: c#, inheritance

i have these 2 classes

```cs
class Animal
{
    public string name;

    public virtual void MakeSound()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("some sound");
    }
}

class Dog : Animal
{
    public override void MakeSound()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("bark");
    }
}
```

id like to know where the differences are between these 2 objects?

```cs
Animal dog = new Dog();
Dog dog2 = new Dog();
```

edit: my problem with this is that i do not understand the process/ thought behind these 2 object. Yes, they both are Dog() object, but what I do not understand WHY i have the possibility to assign Animal AND Dog to the type. I get that "assign" is the wrong wording but what it just seems VERY weird to me that I have the possibility to do that.

Programming has treated me "harshly" until now. Everything has to have the right syntax and everything has to be in the right order and everything hast to make sense. If thats not the case i get an error
`List<int> list = new List<int>;` doesn't work, neither does `List<int> list = new List();` nor something else. Thats why I don't get the 2 objects. It seems to me that, functionality wise, they both do and can do the same. But are they actually the same?

Comment: Inheritance: https://www.atlantic.net/vps-hosting/how-to-object-oriented-programming-constructors-inheritance/

Comment: There is no difference between these 2 objects. There is a difference in how they are referenced.

Comment: what do you mean by "differences"? You have 2 completely different objects of type `Dog`. Please be more precise on what you mean.

Comment: maybe you just try it ? And post what you confuse point.

Comment: voting to reopen because OP would not likely know how to be more specific, look at this question from the perspective of someone who is learning OOP, not as one who has mastered it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the Animal class is more generic, you can use only for declaration, for instance if you don't know yet what animal is, and change to another subclass as you need. Imagine you have also:

```
     class Cat: Animal
     {
        public override void MakeSound()
        {
             Console.WriteLine("mew");
        }
      }
```

You could do:

```
        Animal animal = new Dog();
        Dog dog2 = new Dog();
        
        animal.MakeSound();
        
        animal = new Cat();
        animal.MakeSound();
```

And the output is:
bark
mew

If you only use the Dog class, you have to create another variable for Cat.

I hope this help you.

---

**EDIT**

The power can be seen when you make a list or dictionary (or other collection) containing different animals:

```cs
var animals = new List<Animal>();
animals.Add(new Dog("Rover"));
animals.Add(new Cat("Tiger"));

foreach (var animal in animals)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{animal.name} goes:");
    animal.MakeSound();
}
```

Output:

```cs
Rover goes:
bark
Tiger goes:
mew
```

Comment: It would have helped more if you added a new behaviour or property :) the existing example already covered overriding `MakeSound`, so this hasn't actually added anything to the discussion.

Comment: isma, hope its okay that I added to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

There is no big difference.

The only real difference is that if you would implement a public method or property in the `Dog` class which is not in the `Animal` class, you would not be able to access them unless you cast it like `((Dog)dog).SomeProperty`.

Probably the only time you use the `Animal` class instead of the `Dog` class is if you need a `List` containing all the animals.

Comment: "Probably the only time you use the Animal class instead of the Dog class is if you need a List containing all the animals." I strongly disagree. When passing objects around you should be as generic as possible IMHO, meaning pass `Animal` around, not `Dog`, unless you really have to. So it's the other way round.

Comment: ^^ Maybe even only an Interface, Animal (and its descendants) implements.

Comment: Rather than an explicit cast it would be better to demonstrate using a conditional cast via the `is` operator, as you cannot guarantee that the object _IS_ a `Dog`. It is also not worth speculating any _only time_ scenarios, as developers we know there are always exceptions to rules. There are going to be many cases where a reference to `Animal` would not onlybe expected, but also preferred. For type casting docs, please review https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/type-testing-and-cast

Comment: Adding to Chris comment: Starting with c# 9.0, you can code like `Animal animal = ...; if (animal is Dog dog) { ...dog.SomeProperty... }`.